# Passport is authenticating strategies more than once (using multistrategies)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have configured Passport.js to use multiple strategies:

```
passport.authenticate(['bearer', 'facebook-token', 'google-token', 'linkedin-token'],function(err, user, info) ...
```

I am sure that this authenticate function calls only once, but within Passport's source code in the authenticate.js file, I see that some strategies are executing more than once.

Say bearer fails, then I want facebook-token to be attempted.

My facebookTokenStrategy code is the following:

```
facebookTokenStrategy: new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
}, function(access_token, refresh_token, profile, done) {
    someFunction().then(function(user) {
        return done(null, user)
    }, done)
}),
```

I have placed console logs at many of these points and checked that the facebook-token strategy does work with the proper access token, but the strategy "succeeds" more than once, and my API call to Node.js ends up saying "Cannot GET /api/authenticate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Was calling done() twice in the bearer strategy.